# Relation between spectrums of algebra and subalgebra

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

I want to ask this. Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a Banach algebra and $\mathcal{B}$ a subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$. I want to show that if $σ_{\mathcal{A}}(x)$ does not seperate $\mathbb{C}$ then $σ_{\mathcal{A}}(x) = σ_{\mathcal{B}}(x)$.

Any help/hint would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can answer your question by using this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070065/let-a-and-b-be-a-banach-algebra-with-1-in-a-subset-b-1-is-the-identity-let/4070155#4070155

Comment: @Ruy Thanks for the reply. But how can I show the equality? That is the part where I'm stuck. Thanks again.